# Table cell width wider than cells content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I don't understand why is table cells width wider than cell's content.

I would like to have width of column `Artikel` aligned with content. What I've already tried is set `th` width - but this is fixed and it doesn't align with content. Is there any other solution?

My example is [here](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/boojye?editors=1010)

[image]

Comment: Add the class shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983301/how-to-make-a-table-column-be-a-minimum-width). This will force the column to be the minimum width possible - specified by the content of that column

Comment: I've tried this on my example and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the class `table` from `bootstrap.min.css` which is as below.

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

So if you remove the `table` class the results is as needed.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it works. How to make table width 100% and at the same time make cells width align with content? (table width should be 100% inside given div with class='col-sm-12')

Comment: @FrenkyB If the table width is 100%, then obviously there will be extra space. just think about it, it would be better if you just center the table, if you don't want that space!